# adding functionality to chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, developer-tools

I'd like to add functionality to chrome's developer tools.
In particular it would be nice to have a most used files option to the list of scripts I'm looking at. Also would be nice to hide some scripts from my list that im not currently interested in.

Any guidance on where to start would be appreciated ? e.g. is this something possible with an addon or is it core chrome functionality ie is this a patch to the chrome source ?

[image: sample func idea]

Comment: will you please try ctrl+shift+i to your crome browser window. if your not getting it please install firebug (extension) and than try.

Comment: It is not clear for me how will you manage the list of the hidden source files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small guide about extending Chrome DevTools.
http://smus.com/extending-chrome-developer-tools

The guide about hacking the DevTools is here http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/contributing.html

Answer (score 2):

Chrome doesn't currently allow messing with the developer tools. There is an experimental [chrome.experimental.devtools API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.devtools.html) however that allows you to add your own pages to the devtools. Experimental APIs needs to be enabled on `chrome://flags`, otherwise extensions using them won't install. And of course you cannot upload such extensions to the Chrome Web Store. If that's ok for you then you can try to implement something. Eventually these APIs will be marked as stable but I have no idea when this will be.